# How cleanly remove a perk in Fallout 3?

Tags: pc, fallout-3

I regret investing in some perks which provide skill points (can be trivial to earn and [all categories can apparently be maxed](https://old.reddit.com/r/Fallout/comments/bg5mma/how_to_max_out_every_skill_in_fallout_3/)), currently I only pursue active effects. Is it possible to remove perks with the console in such a way that their effects are removed and they disappear from the in-game stat screens (to avoid future confusion?).

[image: perk1]

[image: perk2]

Comment: Just note that if you intend to follow the standard level requirement of perks, it may be difficult to avoid all skill point perks completely, as *most* level 2 perks are just skill point raisers.

Comment: @king14nyr: Thank you, worth noting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `player.removeperk` console command — see [a full list of IDs here](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/pc/918428-fallout-3/faqs/54677).

For instance, to remove your perks use the commands:

```
player.removeperk 00069310
player.removeperk 0004494E
```

Since the perks are to my knowledge only granted when leveling up, you have to use the reverse `player.addperk` command (see the IDs again) to "spend" your "regained" perk points.